# Does const variable in header produce multiple local symbols like static?

Tags: c++, static, constants, extern

There are plenty of answers around SO regarding variables declared in header either as `const`, `static` or `extern`.

But I don't understand if `const` variable in a header which has internal linkage, does that mean this variable will consume memory space in executable equivalent to multiple of translation units that included the variable?

For example, consider this (comments are my understanding, please correct if wrong):

**header.h**

```
static int var1 = 1; // each TU has it's own copy, consumes extra memory for each inclusion
const int var2 = 2; // same as above, exe consumes memory multiple of TU inclusions
extern int var3; // variable is unique, consumes memory only in a single place.
```

From my understanding `static` and `const` are the same, both have internal linkage, there are multiple copies, except that const can't be modified.

Basically what's the difference between `const` and `static` regarding consumption of memory and in which case TU's will (or wont) have multiple copies of these variables?

**UPDATE**

I've also seen declarations like this:

```
const static int x = 0;
```

if both static and const implies internal linkage whats the point of above declaration then? why just not use:

```
const int x = 0;
```

it's the same thing? or is there a difference?

Comment: Full explanation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: @RichardCritten which portion of the document explains `const` vs `static` variable?  I'm not able to find that either with CTRL + F or without.

Comment: That's because `const` is part of the type of the variable, it has nothing to do with linkage and / or storage duration.

Comment: @VTT Yes it's part of the variable type, but `const` also implies internal linkage, how do you say then "it has nothing to do with linkage"?

Comment: @metablaster section __Linkage__ >> __internal linkage.__ :   _"Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have internal linkage:"_ ... _"...non-volatile non-template (since C++14) non-inline (since C++17) __const__-qualified variables..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten ok good, both `static` and `const` have internal linkage, but the question is whether that implies multiple copies of simbols per TU and that both `const` and `static` variables consume extra memory space equivalent of multiple TU's inclusions in final executable. and is there any other difference between them?

Comment: My reading is that this would be a quality of implementation issue (and therefore outside the scope of the Standard).  `static` needs separate storage as different translation units would not expect to change each others statics.  `const` however may or may not have storage associated with it (compiler substitutes the magic value), and may or may not be folder by the linker.

Comment: Yes, they could easily be duplicated. You can put the same named constant variable with different values into different translation units. But the compiler usually puts `const int` variables into the object file only, if it needs to (address taken, for example).